# Joomla - "Unknown column 'aid' in 'order clause'

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm working with a joomla installation and have built a component using component-creator.com.I've used it in the past without problems, and was doing fine with the current component.  However, on the component creator site, I changed two fields from being text fields to textareas.

I built, downloaded and installed it, but when I try to view the frontend page that lists all the entries, I get an error that reads:  "Unknown column 'aid' in 'order clause'.  I don't understand what that means and have never even had a column called 'aid', nor do I see in the component's php files where a query for 'aid' is even called.  I've googled looking for a solution, and tried Joomla database fix tool with no luck.

Can someone please explain to me what is suddenly causing this error and how I can go about fixing it?

Thanks.

Comment: it seems probably a.id is entered as aid. If you can upload the component somewhere i can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

In the model of the view that is sending the error, find this line and correct it by the corresponding field

```
parent::populateState('aid', 'DESC');
```